# Kendo UI Grid - Display foreign key value instead of ID

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

The grid uses a drop down list that contains foreign key values. Right now, I can select an item but I can only see the corresponding item ID instead of it's name in the grid.

I tried following the steps in [this post](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/grid/displaying-foreign-key-value-in-clientrowtemplate-of-kendoui-grid.aspx) but all I see is 'undefined' in the grid row. Any ideas?

By the way, I'm using the open source version of Kendo UI where everything is in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually requested for support from Telerik and the working solution is shown in this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/OVOCAmu/2/edit).

Answer (score 1):

This is the MVC version, but here, you don't need a template.  See:

http://decisivedata.net/kendo-ui-grid-and-entity-framework-code-first-foreign-key-fields/

Say you want to get the Product name, instead of use ProductID on your Orders table. You'd use a column like:

```
columns.ForeignKey(c => c.ProductID, (IEnumerable)ViewData["Products"], dataFieldText: "ProductName", dataFieldValue: "ProductID");
```

And ensure your model had the foreign key in the Orders model:

```
 [ForeignKey("ProductID")]
 public Product FKProduct { get; set; }
```

And you update the controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {        
    private NorthwindRepository northwindRepository = new NorthwindRepository();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        PopulateProducts();         
        return View(northwindRepository.OrderDetails);     
    }
    private void PopulateProducts()     
    {         
        ViewData["Products"] = northwindRepository.Products;     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a template.

In your model have another field which relates to the name (you will need to set this to the correct value when editing), then use a template like
    "#=name#

Firstly create your column like this:

```
columns.Bound(x => x.ForeignKey).ClientTemplate("#=Name#");
```

then in your Update method in your controller set the Name property on the view model to what you want it to be.

```
viewModel.Name = GetName(viewModel.ForeignKey);
return this.Json(new[] { viewModel }.ToDataSourceResult(request, this.ModelState));
```

Edit 2:
For building the grid in javascript mode you will need to define the column like this:

```
{ field: "ForeignKey", title: "Foreign Key", template: '#=Name#', editor: myEditor}
```

Then define your editor like this:

```
function myEditor(container, options) {
    $('<input required data-text-field="ForeignKeyName" data-value-field="ForeignKey" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
        .appendTo(container)
        .kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: false,
            dataSource: myDataSource
        });
}
```

You may still need to set the value however, if you want to do it on the server side you can use use the method I mentioned above, if you want to do this client side you will need to handle the grid save event and set the value in the data source there.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying , much appreciated. The thing is, I'm not using the server wrappers. In hindsight, should have mentioned that I'm using the open source version of Kendo UI where everything is in JavaScript. I've edited my question.

Comment: Tried your recommendation, but still no luck. Theoretically, wouldn't I have to set the data value field as _ForeignKeyId_ instead of _ForeignKey_? If I use _ForeignKey_, I get foreign key constraint errors and am unable to create new items in the grid.

Comment: In my sample ForeignKey is the ID, and ForeignKeyName is the text value. Could you post a Snippet or JS Fiddle showing the issue your having?

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for clarifying, I've been using the ID anyway. Let me set up a snippet and post the link.